# MYSQL - Max and Min with LIMIT

Tags: mysql

I have a table where I want to select only two lines using "LIMIT 2" and in that two rows I want to apply the "CASE" with the MAX and MIN between the result (2 lines).

But it is selecting all rows and applying the "CASE" in all rows.

How can I apply only with those two results?

Thank you.

```
    Table:

        user | offer
        1    | 10
        1    | 10
        2    | 20
        2    | 20


    Query:

        SELECT (case when max(offer) = min(offer)             
                then 'true'             
                else 'false'        
            end) as info
        FROM user
        ORDER BY offer DESC 
        LIMIT 2

Result that I want to have:

result = true
```

Comment: I took a try at writing an answer, but then I realized I don't understand from your description what you are trying to accomplish with this query. I think you need to explain more fully.

Comment: @BillKarwin I want to select the last two rows (LIMIT 2) and compare the MAX and MIN from only those two rows and give the result TRUE of FALSE.

Comment: This might return what you want: `select case when count(distinct offer) = 1 then 'true' else 'false' as info from (select offer from user order by offer limit 2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take that limit in subquery to fulfill ur requirement.

```
SELECT (case when max(offer) = min(offer)             
                then 'true'             
                else 'false'        
            end) as info 
  From (Select * FROM user
        ORDER BY offer DESC 
        LIMIT 2)
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help. It is giving the result that I want to have. Thank you.